# construct dataset for ner train

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

i have in input :

```
text = "Apple est une entreprise, James Alfred travaille ici"
spans = [
    {
"start":0,
"end":5,
"label":"ORG"
},
{
"start":26,
"end":38,
"label":"PER"
}
]

correspondance_dict = {"PER":2, "ORG": 4 , "O" : 0}
```

i want to tokenize the text and construct label according to spans list i.e :

i want to have in output :

```
tokenized_text = ["Apple", "est", "une", "entreprise", "," , "James","Alfred", "travaille", "ici"]
labels = [4,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0]  #this list constructed with correspondance_dict and spans (4 because Apple is ORG and  the "2,2" because "James,Alfred" is person
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use a `huggingface`'s pipeline in other parts of your program, it's easy to aggregate output text chunks using an appropriate strategy.

The documentation for a thorough explanation is available [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.24.0/en/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.TokenClassificationPipeline.aggregation_strategy)!

```
from transformers import pipeline

# Initialize the NER pipeline
ner = pipeline("ner", aggregation_strategy="simple")

# Phrase
phrase = "David helped Peter enter the building, where his house is located."

# NER task
ner_result = ner(phrase)

# Print result
print(ner_result)
```

output:

```
[{'entity_group': 'PER', 'score': 0.99642086, 'word': 'David', 'start': 0, 'end': 5}, {'entity_group': 'PER', 'score': 0.99559766, 'word': 'Peter', 'start': 13, 'end': 18}]
```

Comment: i know how i did this but it is not the answer to my question , i want to have the two lists in output not to extract NER from sentence